# Orchard CMS, Lucene indexing does not return any value

Tags: orchardcms

I am working on Orchard CMS trying to create a custom result listing for Lucene indexed entities. The entity has a price field, which has been successfully indexed. I could see the entities using Luke - Lucene Index Toolbox. I am trying to retrieve them with following snippets, but it always returns 0:

```
var searchBuilder = _indexProvider.CreateSearchBuilder("Search");
var x = searchBuilder.WithField("Price", 200000).Search().Count();
```

I not sure why the results are not being returned. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is an int serach.

Try add ExactMatch() like this:

```
var x = searchBuilder.WithField("Price", 200000).ExactMatch().Search().Count();
```